# Instagram API script - Count images and display max 10

Tags: php, api, instagram

Below you can see the script I use to access the "api" and display max 10 images. That works so far, but if a user has less than 10 images, it errors. How can I display MAX 10 images and if the user has less than 10, then display only the amount of images the user has?

Script:

```
<?php


    // Get data from Instagram User
    $url        = "https://www.instagram.com/wsj/media/";
    $instagramdata  = @file_get_contents($url);
    $instagramdata  = json_decode($instagramdata, true);


?><div class="instagramfeed"><?php

for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++){
    $instagramimages = $instagramdata['items'][$i]['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];
    $instagrampage = $instagramdata['items'][$i]['code'];
    $instagramlikes = $instagramdata['items'][$i]['likes']['count'];



    ?><a href="http://instagram.com/p/<?=$instagrampage?>" target="_blank"><?php
    ?><div class="instagramimages" style="background:url(<?=$instagramimages?>)no-repeat center;background-size:cover;"><?php

    ?>
    <div class="instagramimagesoverlay">
        <span class="instagramimagesoverlaytext"><i class="fa fa-heart fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $instagramlikes;?></span>
    </div>
    <?php



    ?></a><?php
    ?></div><?php



}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the Count for the number of items in the array, there are a number of ways of doing that but here is one

You also seem to have some unnecessary `<?php .. ?>` pairs with nothing in them, so I removed those too.

```
<?php
    // Get data from Instagram User
    $url            = "https://www.instagram.com/wsj/media/";
    $instagramdata  = @file_get_contents($url);
    $instagramdata  = json_decode($instagramdata, true);


?>
    <div class="instagramfeed">
<?php
    $cnt = count($instagramdata['items']) > 10 ? 10 : count($instagramdata['items']);
    for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++){
        $instagramimages = $instagramdata['items'][$i]['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];
        $instagrampage = $instagramdata['items'][$i]['code'];
        $instagramlikes = $instagramdata['items'][$i]['likes']['count'];
?>
    <a href="http://instagram.com/p/<?=$instagrampage?>" target="_blank">
        <div class="instagramimages" style="background:url(<?=$instagramimages?>)no-repeat center;background-size:cover;">
        <div class="instagramimagesoverlay">
            <span class="instagramimagesoverlaytext"><i class="fa fa-heart fa-1x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<?php echo $instagramlikes;?></span>
        </div>
    </a>
    </div> <!-- this probably belongs outside the foreach loop-->
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks alot for your solution. If a user has 100 images for example, will this script output 100images then? Could I limit, so it processes only max 10 images?

Comment: Ahh.. forgot about the max 10 limit, give me a second

Comment: Silly me, thats better. Sorry about that first attempt

Comment: Perfect, man! :)) Thanks alot. Thats exactly what I wanted to achieve.